# How can I unhide ghc library using runhaskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, runhaskell

I'm building simple script with `runhaskell` and I try to use `FastString` from `ghc-7.10.2`. Simply:

```
import FastString

main = putStrLn "Hello SO"
```

running it with `runhaskell Main.hs` results in error:

```
Main.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module ‘FastString’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘ghc-7.10.2’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I know that I can build it with `cabal` and specify `ghc` as dependency, but I really need to do it with `runhaskell`.

How can I unhide ghc library using `runhaskell`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```bash
$ ghc-pkg expose ghc
```

---

Well, `runhaskell` is basically a wrapper around `runghc`, and `runghc` is basically `ghc`. All of them follow the same rules: they can only import *exposed* packages from your configured database.

Using `ghc-pkg describe {package-name}`, one can get information about a certain package. The important field here is `exposed`:

```
$ ghc-pkg describe ghc | grep expose
exposed: False
exposed-modules:
```

As you can see, the package isn't exposed (therefore it's hidden). Using `ghc-pkg expose`, you can unhide it:

```
$ ghc-pkg expose ghc
```

Keep in mind that you need permissions if you're changing the settings of your system wide package database.